# Typescript, transform an object into another type while preserve its key in the output type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

Suppose I write a code like this

```js
type ResourceDecorator = (input: UserResourceDefinition) => DecoratedResourceDefinition
const decorate: ResourceDecorator = ...

const resources = decorate({
   Book1: {
      resourceName: 'my-book',
      resourceType: 'book'
   },
   Pencil1: {
      resourceName: 'my-pencil',
      resourceType: 'pencil'
   } 
})
```

I want to write the function `decorate(...)` such that all first-level keys in the input type (`Book1`, `Pencil1`) are preserved in the output type. In other words, I want to use the output `resources` like this

```js
// somewhere else

console.log(resources.Book1.resourceName)

// the decorate() function will add some programmatically 
// defined properties in addition to the user definition.
console.log(resources.Book1.exampleDecorationProperty)
```

I have tried the indexable object syntax like this but it does not work.

```js
export interface UserResourceDefinition {
    [key: string]: {
        resourceName: string,
        resourceType: string,
    }
}

export interface DecoratedResourceDefinition {
    [key: string]: {
        resourceName: string,
        resourceType: string,
        exampleDecorationProperty: string
    }
}

type ResourceDecorator = (input: UserResourceDefinition) => DecoratedResourceDefinition
const decorate: ResourceDecorator = (input) => {
   return Object.entries(definition).map(([resourceKey, userDef]) => ({
        resourceName: userDef.resourceName,
        resourceType: userDef.resourceType,
        resourceKey: resourceKey,
        exampleDecorationProperty: someFunction(userDef)
   })).reduce((accumObj, decoratedDef) => ({ ...accumObj, [decoratedDef.resourceKey]: decoratedDef }), {});
}
```

It does not work because the type of the output `resources` does not know it has property `Book1` and `Pencil1`.

```js
// somewhere else

// The auto completion cannot infer 'resources.Book1'
console.log(resources.Book1.resourceName)

// The compiler does not complain about non-existing property 'Foo'
console.log(resources.Foo.resourceName)
```

It is possible to do this with Typescript?

Comment: You can define the type you want using generics ` T & {[key in keyof T]: {exampleDecorationProperty:string}}`, but I'm not sure there is an elegant way of convincing TS that the result of your function conforms to that type. Idk if you're okay with `return res as  T & {[key in keyof T]: {exampleDecorationProperty:string}}`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova your solution is promissing, but a new problem is I don't know how to write an implementation in the function to satisfy the type definition. It seems `Object.entries().reduce()` erase all the information about the input type. Do you have some idea to let me try it out. Thank you.

Comment: That is the problem, I don't think there is a way for TS to figure out that the type after decoration is correct. So if you're confident you're doing it right you can return the result stating it is the type you need (using `as` keyword). This means the code outside of the decorator function will be protected by the type checks, but the function itself will be vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I'm suggesting is

```
const decorate= <T extends {}>(input:T) : T & {[key in keyof T]: {exampleDecorationProperty:string}} =>
{
    let decorated = {...input}
    const keys = Object.keys(input) as Array<keyof T>
    keys.forEach(k => decorated[k]={...decorated[k], exampleDecorationProperty:'whatever'})
    return decorated as T & {[key in keyof T]: {exampleDecorationProperty:string}};
}
```

If it won't work for you, I can delete this answer so you get better chance to get help from others :)